# How to edit the Android context menu?

Tags: customization, vanilla-android

I've encountered [an app](https://github.com/foobnix/LibreraReader) which adds itself to the global Android context menu. The entry has even overtaken native Firefox options in the past and currently slows down my workflow in every app where the context menu is relevant.
I may also want to remove some other options such as 'cut' (for text).

[image: screenshot]

Suggesting to uninstall this specific app isn't an answer. Using ADB is fine. I'm rooted if that's a necessity.

Comment: I wasn't able to think of hugely relevant tags. I'm indeed running an AOSP ROM.

Comment: From [Ian Lake
's Medium article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/custom-text-selection-actions-with-action-process-text-191f792d2999#.ytta438f7), `Intent.ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT` should be the culprit. However, I haven't researched if it's possible to block/disable it as an end-user.

Comment: [How to set which options appear on the text selection toolbar?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/238580/how-to-set-which-options-appear-on-the-text-selection-toolbar#comment316345_238580)

Comment: Still applies to [the 8.4.52 version](https://github.com/foobnix/LibreraReader/releases/tag/8.4.52) (Android 11).