# How to set which options appear on the text selection toolbar?

Tags: settings, default-applications, menu

I'm referring to the menu that appears when you tap and hold on some text to select it. How do you change which options appear by default and which appear in the extra (. . .) menu?

I have to translate text regularly, and Google Translate used to appear on the text selection menu without tapping into the extra options. As of a week ago, Google Translate has been moved to the extra options menu, and a regular Google search is in its old place, so it's an extra tap for me to translate text. I feel this is a system setting somewhere but cannot find anything about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As an end user you cannot do anything about it. As an app developer you can handle [`android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT) in one of your app's Activities. That Activity's label will appear in text selection context menu in all installed apps. You can get your own app developed to add any custom options in the menu.

Comment: Thank you @IrfanLatif! It's a bit frustrating that end users cannot customize the menu, but please add this as an answer so I can mark it as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of [How to edit the Android context menu?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228224/218526)