# How to Customize Floating Menu When doing Long Press?

Tags: applications, settings, android-11

When you long press a text from browser or other apps that are *clickable*, normally you will see copy, select all web search and the triple dots, for instance just like on this screenshot below when I long press a text on Chrome browser

[image]

Suppose I tap the triple dots, this is what will appear:

[image]

As you can see, there are entries which some of those are the apps that I installed, that means, whichever apps that I install and it's *available* to appear in the list will be listed there.

However, not every app can do this. For instance this dictionary app that has different list:

[image]

And this one has Google translate in the front because I installed the app and it has a bit different entries from the list

[image]

[image]

From the experience like we can force an android app in a dark mode though the developer of the app doesn't provide this feature by turning on the toggle button in the *Developer Options* in the setting, I'm thinking that it's not that impossible to, for instance, change the behavior of the long press so that I can modify what should be in the list.

This will be very helpful if it's possible. Because when I'm too lazy to open another app and I need a translator, I can just long press the text and the translator is listed in the floating menu.

At first, I was thinking it's just designed by default, I mean, suppose the developer app A is making it possible that the app B will be listed in the floating menu when the user long presses the clickable text. Until I realized that when I install app C, and the app A itself is so old, and unlikely that app C will appear but it does, which means any app as long as it's compatible, they will be listed there.

Comment: Dupe, but no solutions found yet: [How to set which options appear on the text selection toolbar?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/238580/44325), [How to edit the Android context menu?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228224/44325)