# What adds "Translate" item to selected text's context menu and how to get rid of this

Tags: google, android-13, realme

I am trying to figure out which application or which application's setting is adding "Translate" button to the selected text's context menu in Wikipedia app:

[image]

Wikipedia mobile app's developers [says](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T346999) that this is not their problem and that this item comes from some other place, not from their app.

I *do have* Google application installed. I *don't have* Google Translate app installed. I have never used translate functionality out of Google app (to be honest, until now I wasn't aware that there is such). And certainly I didn't enable such damn thing intentionally.

My gear:

- Phone: `realme GT 5G (RMX2202)`
- Android: `13 Kernel version 5.4.147-qgki-ga616720f33728`

Can someone tell me, if it is possible to turn this thing off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options to try:

- Uninstall the Google app. If this is not possible,next
- Disable the Google app

These were suggested since *Google Translate* is baking itself in the option menu.

The second option [worked for the OP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/253264/what-adds-translate-item-to-selected-texts-context-menu-and-how-to-get-rid-of?noredirect=1#comment343307_253264)

Comment: I can confirm that the Google app added this feature. On my Pixel 3a, the "Translate" context menu is overloaded by 3 apps: Google, (Google) Translate, and a 3rd-party Chinese dictionary app.

Comment: However, there should be an option buried somewhere to disable such behavior.

Comment: @andreszs unlikely, and it's a known fact that it's not possible to modify them either (ref: [How to set which options appear on the text selection toolbar?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/238580/44325), [How to edit the Android context menu?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228224/44325))

Comment: @andreszs "There should be" -- yes! "There is" -- no! (it this particular scenario thanks goodness, it is; in most others no). It's a Google world. You, the dully user are too stupid to know what you need or want... #loveGoogle.

Answer (score -1):

> And certainly I didn't enable such damn thing intentionally.

Of course you didn't. Google keeps adding + enabling useless features endlessly, as you can see in the dedicated Google entry in the **Settings** menu. If you are lucky enough, such setting can be disabled somewhere here. Good luck finding the relevant option though.

[image]

I only keep the Google app for its QR scanner and camera translation feature, so disabling it would be quite an extreme option. Other people may use it for 99% of their daily tasks including searching and browsing from the app's crippled, built-in webview that disguises itself as Chrome, something which I did manage to completely **disable** (for now). As a side note, I'm probably the only Android user that browses the web with Opera and not Chrome nor the Samsung Browser.

Comment: Well... I have QR scanner and camera translation feature provided by 3rd party solution, but I must keeping Google app since uninstalling or disabling it is not an option under my gear! :) #loveGoogle